Compile and execute a java file which is having import statements of a spring-boot based application jar file
Below is the code which we want to compile and execute at run time through a spring-boot based application. Here the below code will be provided by our system admins through our UI, which will be passed to our backend application in string format. Now the backend which is running as spring-boot application, have to compile and execute it.
Given that this dynamic code will have import statements from 2 jar files :
1> an external jar which contains only data models and no logic.
2> The current spring-boot application itself, which has some logic defined in classes.
Objective of this dynamic code is to utilize the data model classes and invoke public methods that are available with in the spring-boot application from where we want to compile/execute the dynamic code.
package ai.myapps.service.triggers;

import ai.myapps.config.WebClientConfig;
import ai.myapps.service.DynamicCode;
import ai.myapps.dao.transaction.Student;
import ai.myapps.dao.transaction.Employee;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import java.util.List;

public class MyDynamicCode extends WebInterface implements DynamicCode {
public <T> T execute(List<T> args) {
    Student student= (Student) args.get(0);
    Employee employee= new Employee();
    employee.setId(student.getId());
    employee.setName(student.getName());
    employee.setContractStartDate(student.getLastWorkingDate());
    return (T) employee;
}

}
Assuming above code is in string format, we are triggering below method from rest controller to compile and execute that piece of code:
private Class<?> compileJavaCode(String javaCode) throws Exception {
    SimpleCompiler compiler = new SimpleCompiler();
    compiler.setParentClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader()); // Set the parent class loader

    ByteArrayOutputStream errStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    compiler.setCompileErrorHandler(new ErrorHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleError(String message, Location location) {
            // Handle compilation error
           log.error("Compilation error: " + message+"  "+ location.getLineNumber());
            // You can also write the error to the error stream
            try {
                errStream.write(("Compilation error: " + message + "\n").getBytes());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }
    });

    compiler.cook(javaCode);
}

Issue is, during compilation time, the dynamic code is not getting compiled as the compiler is not identifying the path of either the current application(spring-boot) nor the data-model jar failing with error MyDynamicCode.java:1: error: package  ai.myapps.config does not exist. Given that data-model.jar is also packaged in spring-boot application as library.
    ai.myapps.dao       -- this package is in data-model.jar
     ai.myapps.service   -- is with in the current application
    ai.myapps.config    -- is with in the current application`

Screenshot shows the expanded view of my spring-boot application
Screenshot shows the expanded view of my spring-boot application for understanding of the package structure.
Kindly let me know what am I missing here.

The "runtime" tag seems odd here. I know what you are doing is at runtime, but I am not sure what value adding this tag provides.
